# Could not find wp-load.php issue

Tags: git, repository, wp-blog-header.php

I am setting up a Wordpress site into a Git repository, and as a result have moved the wp-content directory outsite of the Wordpress core directory (which is permitted as per http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php).

I have moved the index.php and the wp-config.php file into the root directory, and edited the following line to include the Wordpress directory:

```
require('./WordPress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

In the wp-config.php file, I've added (as per http://efeqdev.com/website-development/this-is-how-we-version-control-and-deploy-our-wordpress-websites-with-git/) :

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://dev.example.com/WordPress');
define('WP_HOME',    'http://dev.example.com');
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://dev.example.com' . '/wp-content');
```

Yet when I try load the site at http://dev.example.com I'm getting the following error:

"Could not find wp-load.php".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is confusing, why are you using a `require` if the index and config is where it should be.

Comment: The `require` is in index.php, the other information is in wp-config.php.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct